# Why some zip file download become error in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, zip, nodejs-stream

I tried to download zip files using node-fetch.

File successfully download and I can read the json file inside the zip using adm-zip NPM package.

But some times getting error when reeding the downloaded file. The zip file is corrupted during download.

When unzipping from file, it goes to `.cpgz` format

```
async function download(url, location) {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(location);
            res.body.pipe(fileStream);
            res.body.on("error", (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
            fileStream.on("finish", function () {
                resolve();
            });
        });
        return
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Err on download files ", e)
    }
}
```

Reading this file using `const zip = new AdmZip(file);` throwing error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found`

I just make console for in the first section of code

```
const res = await fetch(url);
console.log(res)
```

Successfull files return `PassThrough { _readableState: ReadableState { ..... ..... writable: true,`

But for failed files

```
Gunzip {
  _writeState: Uint32Array [ 0, 0 ],
  _readableState: ReadableState {
....
....
writable: false,
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: can you provide some example `loaction`?

Comment: #2 Are you sure the `ZIP` file sent in the `req.body`? I guess the `form-data` has some other location.

Comment: Location is path inside the system to save zip file

Comment: And does it has the .zip extension?

Comment: Yeah. It contains uniqId.zip

Comment: Some files are saved and some files are note fetch. These files can't be unzip. It goes to cpgz format

Comment: Gunzip { ..... .... writable: false}  for the corrupted files

Comment: url is the location for downloading a zip files

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite a bit your code, depending on this SO: [Node.js + request - saving a remote file and serving it in a response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237460/node-js-request-saving-a-remote-file-and-serving-it-in-a-response)

```
const request = require('request');

async function download(url, location) {
    try {

        const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(location);
        
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

          const res = request(url);

          res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            // instead of loading the file into memory
            // after the download, we can just pipe
            // the data as it's being downloaded
            fileStream.write(chunk);
          });

          res.on('end', function() {
            resolve();
          });
        });
        
        return
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Err on download files ", e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Same Error -> Error: Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found